# Adding button in custom adapter for each item in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, adapter

I'm trying to get a listView to have a button that corresponds to each item on the listView. For example, if I have a product in the list, i want to click the button and display the information for that specific product when i click the button. How can i add an on click listener in the adapter for my button so that it works according to each item in the listview?

This is my custom array adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Bean> mList;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use convertView recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}
}
```

And this is my Button

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Information"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Add Button in ListView rows same way as you have added TextView and ImageView. is there any problem?

Comment: Add the button to your xml file content_orders, then add it to the custom adapter ViewHolder, and every row in your ListView will include a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the button view into the your row layout with the Textview and ImageView.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use convertView recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
holder.clickableButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
               //Code goes here

            }  
        });  

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Strange this answer is accepted but where you declared clickableButton and bind view holder with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the click listener to the button in your `getView()` method. Then you can use references to 'holder' to customize what ever list item specific action you want.

Answer (score 0):

If button xml code that you provided is inside content_orders layout. Then the code should be like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Bean> mList;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use convertView recycle
    if(convertView==null){
    holder=new ViewHolder();
    convertView =   LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
    holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
holder.btn= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

//set text and url
holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // do something 
Toast.makeText(mContext,String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button btn;

}
}
```